# Should sex be done only for procreation?

Tags: sex, kama

Should sex be done only for procreation or can one do it for enjoyment also ? What does scriptures say about it ?

Comment: In yogic shastras its advised to preserve the semen in body, any activity which releases it should be avoided. In Bhagvadgeeta it mentioned about celibacy https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/14

Comment: If by sex you mean penetration of a penis in a vagina then yes.

Answer (score 5):

Scripture says that sex is only for procreation.

> Dharma, understood as the Supreme Good of man, can never have wealth
> as its reward. Nor has wealth, understood as an aid to the achievement
> of Dharma, been conceived as an aid for the attainment of kama (sexual
> desire). **Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual
> pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life
> unbroken.** And as for life, it has the quest of the Supreme Truth as
> its end – not certainly Karma (i.e. performance of rituals and social
> duties) for the attainment of wealth (prosperity here and heaven
> hereafter).

Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.2.9-10

Comment: Thanks but Could you please tell who has spoken these things ?

Comment: Suta Ugrasravas, the son of Romaharshana, spoke these in answer to the questions asked by Saunaka and other Rishis.